# Как так сокращают код?

Tags: c++, c, соревнование

Решал задачи на [acmp.ru](http://acmp.ru), и в самой простой [задаче](http://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=108), где надо просто считать и вывести число, в [рейтинге](http://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=bstatus&id_t=108&lang=CPP) есть решение вполовину короче моего(всего лишь 35 сим.)! Это читерство или волшебство?
Ну как можно придумать решение короче этого?

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << a;
} // 59 символов
```

<sup>На этом сайте самые лучшие решения те, которые самые короткие.</sup>

Comment: Вообще-то это решение не соответствует задаче. Там надо открывать входной файл с именем `INPUT.TXT`, потом выходной файл...

Comment: @VTT Там есть два пути — либо считывать и выводить в файл, либо считывать и выводить в консоль.

Comment: Даже здесь никто не знает... это волшебство...

Comment: @VerNick Так а тут многие пишут программы профессионально, соответственно извращениями по сокращению кода не занимаются.

Comment: Можете не переживать, умение сокращать код не коррелирует с проффесионализмом разработчика. Как правило, стараются писать чистый и читабельный код, который легко понимать и сопровождать. Например, ваш код хорошо читается, 3 строки - 3 действия, создали переменную (неплохо бы проинициализировать заодно ;), считали туда что-то, это что-то вывели обратно. А вот это `std::cout << std::cin.rdbuf();` уже читается сложнее, т.к. в одной строке идут два действия, и на реальном проекте такой код врядли встретится.

Comment: В большинстве случаев решения таких задач пишутся не на реальных языках (С или С++ например), а на "суржиках", реализуемых конкретными компиляторами в умолчательных конфигурациях. Например, в вашем варианте можно попробовать опустить тип возвращаемого значения `int` из объявления `main`. Это запрещено и в С, и в С++, но GCC "схавает". И вот уже код стал короче...

Comment: @AnT, Так вот все дело в том, что если подключить `stdlib.h`, и написать `main` c пустым телом и без `int`, это уже 27 символов. А самое короткое решение - 35

Comment: Там есть ссылка на статью автора самого короткого решения именно на тему сокращения кода: https://iqbotan.blogspot.com/2012/12/c-acmp.html . Не знаю, есть ли в ней ответ.

Comment: @AnT Да, я читал эту статью и пытался по ней сокращать. Но код не слишком сокращался.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Так как педантичной "стандартности" и "определенности поведения" С кода не требуется, завязываясь на особенности компилятора GCC в его конфигурации по умолчанию можно сократить код до

```
main(){char*gets(),b[9];puts(gets(b));}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf02104f47ad8b3c

(по мотивам ответа @vegorov). Памятуя, однако, что функции `gets` в стандартной библиотеке формально больше нет.

Можно даже совсем грубо, ибо длина входной строки по условию не превосходит 3 (в предположении о том, что ведущие нули в записи чисел не допускаются), а тип `int` в GCC имеет размер 4

```
main(){int*gets(),b;puts(gets(&b));}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c64f32776b7fa150

а также

```
b;*gets();main(){puts(gets(&b));}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e92785b2be0324a6

Это уже 33 символа.

---

А на 32-битной платформе (т.е. на платформе, где размер указателя совпадает с размером типа `int`) можно даже обойтись и без объявления `gets`, хотя это будет уже совсем грубым, наглым и грязным хаком

```
b;main(){puts(gets(&b));}
```

К сожалению, онлайновых компиляторов GCC c библиотеками для `-m32` я не нашел. Только https://godbolt.org/z/j3Ye9u .

Однако если переменная `b` окажется расположенной в той области 64-битного адресного пространства, где старшие 32 бита адреса являются нулевыми, то такой код с высокой долей вероятности будет работать и на 64-битной X86 платформе: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b70346370d1f08f6

Comment: Все равно ошибка выходит когда пытаюсь запустить.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLX4Y.png

Comment: @Ver Nick: Как именно запустить? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf02104f47ad8b3c

Comment: @Ver Nick: Это "решение" нужно компилировать именно в режиме С, а не в режиме С++.

Comment: А, все понял, завтра скомпилю и, возможно приму ответ.

Comment: а если там есть символ не цифра?...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Не понял. Какая разница, какой там символ?

Comment: @AnT, читать нужно число, а не любой символ...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Так `gets` читает *строку*. Ему все равно, что читать. Прочитает все до конца строки. Главное, чтобы переполнения не возникло.

Comment: Ну вот я о том же: а если там  есть символ нечисло (!isdigit) ?...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Не понимаю. По условию задачи ничего подобного там быть не может и рассматривать такие ситуации не нужно. Однако данный код читает что угодно (вплоть до длины 8) и копирует на выход. Если там "нечисло" или нет - роли не играет.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan В задаче нету тестов на строку. Так что все пройдет.

Comment: @AnT Он имел ввиду что делать, если то что считали — не число. Но в  задаче нету тестов на не число. Так что все пройдет.

Comment: А от `golf2.c:(.text+0x24): warning: the 'gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.` удалось избавиться?

Comment: @avp: Это, я думаю, непобедимо.

Comment: @AnT, только sed-ом если -) ?

Comment: `b;main(){puts((read(0,&b,4),&b));}` пользуясь всеми подсказками  -- 34 (!) символа, no warnings, и работает (?) в 64-бит убунте

Comment: Держите компилятор, где запускается ваш самый грязный код: https://www.onlinegdb.com/

Comment: @VerNick там всё равно [64бит компилятор](https://onlinegdb.com/ByZj1EP2m).

Comment: @Ver Nick: Он и на http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com запускается и "работает", но это не более чем случайность, вызванная тем, что переменная `b` получает адрес, который помещается в младшие 32 бита (с нулями в старших 32 битах).

Comment: Могу ещё на байт сократить: `main(b){puts(gets(&b));}`

Answer (score 11):

Вот немного короче.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::cin.rdbuf();
}
```

Радикальный вариант на С89:

```
main(){system("cp INPUT.TXT OUTPUT.TXT");}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xmU8KOAEfhJLen02)

Comment: и получилось ровно в 2 раза короче)

Comment: @SeeSharp У меня 59 символов, у него 57. Это кажется, что в два раза короче :)

Comment: @VerNick ну постой, насколько я знаю `#include <iostream> int main (){}` вещь обязательная. А то что внутри и снаружи, это уже работа. И у вас скажем творческая часть в 2 раза больше чем у **VTT** 2/2=1.

Comment: @SeeSharp Самое короткое решение это 35 символов. Я уверен, что у C++ есть секреты :)

Comment: Самое короткое решение это 35 символов. Я уверен, что у C++ есть секреты :)

Comment: @VerNick сократил до 41

Comment: @VTT если сервер на винде можно сократить `INPUT.TXT` до `I~1` какого-нибудь

Comment: @VTT Ну там только C++, такое извращение не пройдет.

Comment: @VerNick вообще-то пройдёт

Comment: Только это 58 символов с точки зрения проверяющий системы acmp, потому что ещё `#include <stdlib.h>` нужен

Comment: все равно хз как там 35 символов без грязных хаков

Comment: Второй вариант платформозависимый - "cp" это команда Linux, в Windows ее нет.

Comment: @freim, там под MinGW запускается приложение, `cp` есть

Answer (score 11):

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char b[9];
    puts(gets(b));
}
```

48 символов. Следовал советам из статьи [Сокращение кода на C++ для acmp.ru](https://iqbotan.blogspot.ru/2012/12/c-acmp.html)

Comment: А для чего массив чаров? Чтобы `iostream` не использовать?

Comment: @VerNick Ну типа считали строку и вывели строку. Скорее чтобы использовать gets/puts.

Comment: Возможно в тех примерах на 35 символов есть вставки асма или ещё какой хинт.

Comment: Задача была про `int`. Но это даже сокращает код :)

Comment: @Ver Nick: В условии ничего не сказано о том, что прочитать данные надо именно как `int`. Фактически все, что дает нам условие, это то, что длина последовательности не превосходит 3 символов. У придирчивого читателя, конечно, может возникнуть вопрос: а не может ли такое число быть записано как `0000042`...

Answer (score 8):

С и POSIX read/write

```
    avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat golf.c
    main(){char s[4]; write(1, s, read(0, s, 4));}
    avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ wc golf.c
     1  7 47 golf.c
    avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc golf.c -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-implicit-int
    avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ echo 123 | ./a.out
    123
    avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

С потерей остатков читабельности легко сокращается до 40 символов:

`main(){int s;write(1,&s,read(0,&s,4));}`

**Update**

По подсказке @pavel в комментарии получилось **35!!!** (и что характерно, без warnings -), и оказалось достаточно флажка `-w`)

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc golf.c  -w
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat golf.c
s; main(){write(1,&s,read(0,&s,4));}
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Спасибо, @pavel

---

`b;main(){puts((read(0,&b,4),&b));}`

пользуясь подсказками из всех ответов и комментариях
 -- ***34 (!) символа***

Как ни странно `gcc -w` компилирует вообще без ругани, а `./a.out` работает -)

Comment: @VerNick, это форматер такой....

Comment: На сайте проверяли ? я `#include <unistd.h>` не вижу

Comment: Я проверил. 58 символов, потому-что `#include <unistd.h>` надо. Щас нарою ключики компиляции

Comment: @vegorov  На своей `Linux avp-ubu1 4.15.0-38-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 10:59:38 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` проверял.  Без всяких `#include` компилируется. См. ключи компайлера в тексте ответа

Comment: Я понимаю. Речь идёт о проверяющей системе сайта.

Comment: Там вот такое: `g++ -static -fno-strict-aliasing -DACMP -lm -s -x c++ -std=c++14 -Wl,--stack=67108864 -O2 -o task.exe task.cpp`

Comment: А int по умолчанию тип сам не ставится?

Comment: @pavel, отличная подсказка!!! `s;main(){write(1,&s,read(0,&s,4));}` ровно 35!!!

Comment: Осталось только заставить принять эти варианты сайт acmp. У меня пока не получилось.

Comment: @vegorov, да плюньте вы на кресты (переключайтесь на полумесяц -)). Кстати, если ограничиться копированием одного символа, то `main(){putchar(getchar());}` вообще укладывается в 27

Comment: @avp Тут вся фишка в том, что на сайт есть человек который смог сдать эту задачу за 35 символов с теми настройками компилятора. Понимаете?

Comment: @vegorov, понимаю. Но не собираюсь тратить время на доскональное изучение в общем-то скорее вредного для практики языка (С++) (наверняка в его решении какой-то внешний (вызываемый до `main()`) конструктор нетривиально срабатывает)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <ios>
main()
{
system("copy input.txt output.txt");
}

//размер кода: 55 сим
/* мне удалось таким образом достичь 44 сим, но 35 уж совсем читерство, думаю надо 
поискать аналоги copy*/
```

Comment: Уже есть аналогичный [вариант ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/899764/176217).

Comment: Я нашел таки способ 35 сим.) который работает на сайте